# How to add png file to a worksheet in excel?

Tags: r, excel, png, kable

My original file is a kableExtra file and I want to insert it as image to excel workbook.
To do so I saved it to my wd as png. file. I wanted to create new workbook and add png image to worksheet.

I tried to do it with addImage function but I cannot install any package where the function is, although I have the newest R version installed.

Is there any way to save kableExtra file straight into excelworkbook as image? If not how can I do it with png. file without using function addImage?

Thank you for help

Comment: The openxlsx package offers `insertImage` to export images to an Excel file: https://ycphs.github.io/openxlsx/reference/insertImage.html

Comment: Aside from the obvious "don't use excel",  putting images into a document is the **second-worst** thing you can do. (using VB is first).  Just plain do not do it.  You should never be publishing from an excel workbook.